# Check if menu link has submenu JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, toggleclass

I am trying to run some javascript (toggleClass) only if the clicked menu link has a submenu. Is this possible? Thanks in advance for your help.

```
$('#nav a').click(function () {
    if (???) {
        $(this).toggleClass('sf-js-enabled');
    }
});
```

Comment: It's possible, but not without seeing your HTML structure.

Comment: What is it a "submenu" show the HTML please.

Comment: Sorry here is my menu structure, notice there are not classes on my ul or li tags:
    <div id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

Comment: This is what I needed, thanks all for the help

`$('#nav a').click(function () {
 if ($(this).closest("#nav li").find("ul").length > 0) {
  $(this).toggleClass('sf-js-enabled');
 }
})`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#nav a').click(function () {
    // Proceed only if children with your submenu class are present
    if ($(this).find('.submenuClass').length > 0) {
        $(this).toggleClass('sf-js-enabled');
    }
})
```

Comment: `if ($(this).find('.submenuClass'))` will always pass through because jQuery always returns an object even if selector do no match. Check for length.

Comment: `has` is way more efficient, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `has` selector:

```
$('#nav a:has(.submenu)').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('sf-js-enabled');
    });
```

This way jQuery will traverse the DOM only once, and not on each click like in all the other answers you got.

`has` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/):

> Description: Selects elements which contain at least one element that matches the specified selector.

Comment: Is there a way I can use this without a specific submenu class? $('#nav a:has(ul)').click(function () {
this doesn't seem to work

Comment: @user1149767. It should work. But we can't be sure without the HTML. Let me know in a comment once you added it.

Comment: @user1149767. The "Link" should be inside a div\span or some element then change the `:has(.submenu)` to `:has(span\div)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('#nav a').click(function () {
    if ($(this).find('submenuSelector').length) {
        $(this).toggleClass('sf-js-enabled');
    }
})
```

Alternatively you can use `has(selector)` method which reduces the set of matched elements to those that have a descendant that matches the selector or DOM element.

```
$('#nav a').click(function () {
    //Do other suff here

    if ($(this).has('submenuSelector').length) {
        $(this).toggleClass('sf-js-enabled');
    }
})
```

Comment: No need to check it every click. See my answer with `has`.

Comment: What if OP has some thing else to do other than `toggleClass`?

Comment: What if I have some other thing to do on `$('#nav a')` click and just toggle the class only if the current anchor has a submenu?

Comment: Maybe. But that scenario wasn't introduced the question.